# Mocking an method in test cases for groovy code

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

Mocking an method inside a function
But unable to mock it and it's unable fetch the values it throwing an null value

def withStackLocal(Closure cl) {

def proxyHost = Config(key: 'tools.stack.proxy.host')

def proxyPort =  Config(key: 'tools.stack.proxy.port')

}

@Test

voidshouldPassProxyPort(){

stack.proxyPort

assertEquals('80',":${stack.Config(key:'tools.stack.proxy.port')}")

}

Comment: Hiya!  Your code seems to be full of typos and syntax errors.. Can you post the actual code you're using?

Comment: def withStackLocal(Closure cl) {

def proxyHost = Config(key: 'tools.stack.proxy.host')
def proxyPort =  Config(key: 'tools.stack.proxy.port')

}

@Test
voidshouldPassProxyPort(){
browserstack.proxyPort
assertEquals('80',":${stacklocal.Config(key:'tools.stack.proxy.port')}")
}

Comment: That won't compile...Do you have something that we can run that shows the problem? Also, you can edit your question to post the code here